# Quartz 2D's drawing text and NSTimer in custom method

Tags: objective-c, iphone, quartz-2d

i want to show text using quartz 2d. Text will be drawing randomly on different position after each 1 seconds. I am not sure how i can use NSTimer with quartz 2D text. I can draw text in drawRect method where graphics context is already available.
How i will draw text using my custom method myDraw which will be called after 1 second using NSTimer?

If i create my custom Method the graphics context is not available in that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect: in your timer method, causing your drawRect method to be called soon.